# which is the pytesseract dir on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: python, linux, directory, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I can't find the AppData directory on my raspberry pi 4, where can I find it? I tried to search it on web and on stackoverflow but I didn't find anything.

Comment: as I know `AppData` is only on Windows but `Raspberry Pi` usually uses some `Linux`

Comment: if you run `import pytesseract` `print(pytesseract.__file__)` then you should find full path to Python module `pytesseract`. But this is only wrapper on C/C++ program `tesseract` which has to be installed with `apt install tesseract-ocr` (on `Raspbian`) and it may keep data in different place.

Comment: why do you need `AppData`? On Linux Mint I have all data in `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/` but I can also use `tesseract --tessdata-dir other_folder` 
to load languages from `other_folder`. And pytesseract should also use `--tessdata-dir` to use different folder.